# Programmatically add a footer to a view

Tags: 8, views

I need add a footer to a view based on certain conditions. I followed [this article](http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/drupal-8-programmatically-adding-views-footer) and as per my understanding this should work. But this is not giving me any result.

Here is my code:

```
function utility_views_pre_view(ViewExecutable $view, $display_id, array &$args) {
  $item = array(
    'id' => 'area_text_custom',
    'table' => 'views',
    'field' => 'area_text_custom',
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'group_type' => 'none',
    'admin_label' => '',
    'empty' => NULL,
    'tokenize' => NULL,
    'content' => array(
      'value' => "Footer content is great.",
      'format' => "basic_html",
    ),
    'plugin_id' => 'text',
  );
  $view->setHandler($display_id, 'footer', 'area_text_custom', $item);
}
```

Update: Using the above hook the footer is getting called but renders as `Array`

Comment: `based certain conditions` like what?

Comment: The conditions isn't important. That can be handled. But the problem is even the footer isn't showing up anyway. (Without any condition)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to add a Views footer with some code in a custom module.

```
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;
function YOURMODULENAME_views_pre_view(ViewExecutable $view, $display_id, array &$args) {
  if ($view->id() == 'view_machine_name' && $display_id === 'view_display') {
    $options = array(
      'id' => 'area_text_custom',
      'table' => 'views',
      'field' => 'area_text_custom',
      'relationship' => 'none',
      'group_type' => 'none',
      'admin_label' => '',
      'empty' => TRUE,
      'tokenize' => FALSE,
      'content' => ‘Footer content is great.’,
      'plugin_id' => 'text_custom',
    );
    $view->setHandler('view_display', 'footer', 'area_text_custom', $options);
  }
}
```

Reference: [Drupal 8: Programmatically Adding a Views Footer](http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/drupal-8-programmatically-adding-views-footer)

Comment: Thanks Sanjay, I was missing out the content and making it as an array for which the render was messed up.

Comment: If it really helps you. Mark vote up for this answer... Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

User area instead of area_text_custom, below solutions is working for me

```
$item = array(
  'id' => 'area',
  'table' => 'views',
  'field' => 'area',
  'relationship' => 'none',
  'group_type' => 'none',
  'admin_label' => '',
  'empty' => NULL,
  'tokenize' => NULL,
  'content' => array(
    'value' => 'Footer Text goes here',
    'format' => "full_html",
  ),
  'plugin_id' => 'text',
);

$view->setHandler('display_name', 'footer', 'area', $item);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can attach a few other types of content also. Here is an example for a paragraph entity, but any entity type will be similiar.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_view().
 */
function mytheme_views_pre_view(ViewExecutable $view, $display_id, array &$args)
{
  if ($view->id() == 'my-view-id') {

    // Load your entity however you want.
    $paragraph_entity = '[my-entity]'; 

    $item = [
      'id' => 'area',
      'table' => 'views',
      'field' => 'entity_paragraph',
      'empty' => TRUE,
      'target' => $paragraph_entity->uuid(),
    ];

    // This can be header, footer, etc. See ViewExecutable::getHandlerTypes();
    $type = 'header'; 

    // Handler ID. 
    $id = 'paragraph_entity';

    // Finally, attach the handler to the view.
    $view->setHandler($display_id, $type, $id, $item);

  }
}
```

To understand better how to interface with handlers, see 
[core/modules/views/src/ViewExecutable.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21ViewExecutable.php/class/ViewExecutable/8.6.x)

`view->getHandler()` and `view->removeHandler()` are also useful.