# View footer summary

Tags: views, 8

I would like to add a footer to a view with a summary with some row calculations. I have tried creating a plugin (AreaPluginBase) but It doesn't give me the rows nor the arguments of de view. I've followed this [post](https://blog.studio.gd/node/16). I'd need the rows or the exposed filters values to do my calculations. How could I do it?

Comment: There is no view preprocess function available for just the footer but you can probably create a view footer dynamically with some examples from here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/205543/programmatically-add-a-footer-to-a-view, or just use hook_views_pre_view to get appropriate variables into your specific twig template

Comment: You could also implement a custom block plugin and load the view programmatically in order to inspect the results to calculate summary values.